MetricsRegistry bean created before postprocessor when RestTemplateBuilder.build() invoked in autoconfiguration
Using Spring 2.7 with micrometer and prometheus. I have refactored one of my autoconfiguration classes to use RestTemplateBuilder instead of RestTemplate.
With this change, the jvm metrics are no longer available.
The autoconfiguration is invoking builder.build() in its constructor and then passing to various beans it creates.
The problem with this is causes eager instantiation of beans. The RestTemplateBuilder.build() looks for customizers and instantiates org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricRestTemplateCustomizer (which
takes MetricsRegistry as a parameter).  The problem with this is now the MetricsRegistry gets instantiated before the postprocessor and metrics do not work as expected.
If I delay calling build() until its needed, it resolves the issue.
Is it a best practice to avoid calling RestTemplateBuilder.build() this early to avoid this? Any other way to avoid this issue?
